# jQuery's AJAX memory leak of response text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I was debugging my app for memory leaks with the Google Chrome Dev Tools: Heap Snapshots and noticed something strange.

I made an AJAX request to fetch a large blog of JSON and apparently the raw Response Text is sticking around in memory, causing a memory leak in my app.

It seemed unlikely to me that there's a huge memory leak in $.ajax, but I was hoping for an explanation of why this is the case... if I do the same experiment in vanilla JS the leak isn't shown.

**1) Pure JavaScript XHR**

- source: http://jsfiddle.net/HZmT5/2/ (using `XMLHttpRequest`)
- output: http://fiddle.jshell.net/HZmT5/2/show/light/
- No leak shown

**2) Using $.getJSON**

- source: http://jsfiddle.net/JmA8v/1/ (using `$.getJSON`)
- output: http://fiddle.jshell.net/JmA8v/1/show/light/ (leak shown)
- Leak shown, see screenshot:

Screenshot: the entire HTTP Response of the XHR request stuck around in memory. "Snapshot 1" is before the button is pressed. "Snapshot 2" is after. Notice the screenshot below and it's the Comparison of the before/after of the Heap.

The same behavior wasn't reproduced in the pure-JS version.

[image]

(Of course the HTMLDivElement will still remain in the heap since it's in the DOM, but it seems unnecessary that the full JSON object remains in the heap)

Comment: Could be related to the fact `$.getJSON` returns a promise.

Comment: @JulianAubourg is there a workaround / way to to avoid it? Is it a jQuery bug or expected behavior?

Comment: Well, it's expected behaviour that all ajax helpers return a promise (and thus the JSON is kept in memory for the lifetime of the promise). We took great care of dereferencing the XHR object to avoid unnecessary memory retention. What's weird is that the promise is not reclaimed by the garbage collector in your case.

Comment: Right - I'm not holding onto the return value / promise at all and it should have lost scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnOEDlev-So) demonstrates that actually there is no memory leak. jQuery fetches the new version of the string and v8 releases the old one. The reason of that behavior is the fact that V8 engine uses many different tricks for optimization and may keep a reference to an object inside its internal structures and generated code.

The blue bars in the video are the moments in time when profiler found new objects/strings in the v8 heap. The bars become grey when v8 collects these objects as a garbage.

Comment: Your video shows that upon multiple ajax fetches only one tall blue bar remains, but it's not showing that there isn't a leak with the single/latest request. 

So I still don't understand why the non-jQuery code doesn't show the problem, but the jQuery code does... and would be nice to understand an easier way to tell based on screenshots like mine above what is truly a leak and what's not.

Comment: From my point of view if a new object appears and remains in heap after each iterations/action, for example if I pressed a button 10 times and got 10 objects in heap, it is a leak. i.e. there should be at least a linear dependency between number of user actions and amount of used memory. In your case the javascript engine just caches the result for some reason and releases it the next time when you press the button.

Comment: I'll buy this, but it seems wrong/confusing that Chrome is reporting stuff stored in memory in the Heap Snapshot even where there's no external reference to it - after a Garbage Collection is run (which should happen before it takes the snapshot). Makes it hard to debug memory leaks unless its an action that can be repeated over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps missing something, yet jsfiddles at original post appear return same results ?

Also, would

`$.ajaxSetup({cache : false})`

affect results ?

To delete browser cache at chromium/chrome browser, at `Terminal` (*nix) try

`find ~/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache -type f -exec rm -f {} \;`

`find ~/.cache/chromium/Default/Media\ Cache -type f -exec rm -f {} \;`

replacing`chromium` with `chrome` if needed. Alternatively, navigate to the

`chromium` or `chrome` folder at device, navigate to each `Default` and `Media Cache` 
folders within, and delete contents.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `cache` here is referring to the browser caching the http response on disk based on the caching headers of the http response... not whether its cached in-memory.

Comment: As alluded to at post, above, appeared to derive same response, that is "X"'s filling screen, at both jsfiddles jsfiddle.net/HZmT5/2 jsfiddle.net/JmA8v/1 ? Chrome/chromium devtools may provide several "layers" of "memory", depending on the devtools tab utilized. As pointed out above _" The reason of that behavior is the fact that V8 engine uses many different tricks for optimization and may keep a reference to an object inside its internal structures and generated code."-loislo_. What is the requirement ? Please clarify. Thanks